# Want hint and text to have different layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have a textview and i want that the hint for this textview should be centered, but the text that user enters be left-to-right, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to your edittext and change gravity corresponding to its contains. So if there is no any char and thus hint will be displayed - make gravity center and with the 1st entered char make gravity left.